# Conversion problems in C++ (string expected)

Tags: c++, logfiles

I have a function that I cannot touch, Is a "log maker", It puts something to print in a file an show it up when I run the file. The problem is that the function only gets `const string` so if I want to print something I have to convert everything in this data type (I cannot use cout).

itoa & atoi functions are not standard functions so I cannot use it neither. C++ is very "special" with data types and doesn't accept conversions really easy, so this is my question:
How can I convert everytype of data into string for the log purposes?

Probably I should check data type on a function to convert things and returning them into a `stringstream` (witch I have to convert into a string, of course).

So, any advice on how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`boost::lexical_cast` encapsulates the use of `ostringstream`, so you 
could use that.  Otherwise, the code isn't that difficult:

```
template<typename T>
std::string
toString( T const& object )
{
    std::ostringstream results;
    results << object;
    return results.str();
}
```

(There's no reason to use `stringstream` here; `ostringstream` is largely sufficient.

Comment: That's even more easy, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

- std::stringstream

or

- boost lexical_cast<>

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want arbitrary type in string representation `stringstream` intermediate sounds like a solution.

Comment: I'm just feeling like stupid, I was forgetting convert this into a string with `.str();`

Answer (score 0):

I assume the functions expects a const std::string & ?

Your approach with std::stringstream is correct. Alternatively you could simply write a toString() method for the class you wish to directly output. However, usually when one wants to output objects to a file, overloads the << operator for that particular type.